# Deleting comment history

Tags: youtube

How to delete comment history on YouTube & WHY was that feature even added in the first place? That feature just popped up on my account earlier THIS YEAR. I know it's PUBLIC in the comments section,  but considering we CAN'T privatize this feature as we can everything else on our account,  giving others access to pinpoint those same comments from our OWN PAGES,  isn't that somewhat of a violation of privacy, especially for those of us who opt to have inaccessible info on our page?

Answer (score 0):

You can see your own comment history on YouTube, but others can't. The only comment history that others can see is the 3 latest comments made on a channel if you are using a phone. And that feature was made to see the type of comments a person posts on that channel. Other than that feature which lets people see the 3 latest comments on the channel you commented there is no other way for people to see all of your comments.

(Other than the person's channel you are commenting on can see all the comments you made on their channel by searching your name.)

To clarify, no one can see your full comment history on YouTube.